# Angular dependency injection token

Tags: angular

In the examples below the Angular dependency injection system uses the type information to match the requested dependency with the appropriate instance to inject. Why Injector can find dependency (registered provider) by "type-token" from a internal collection in 3 different ways? Is this only possible if type being used as token to inject the instance?

1st

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
...
private firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore)
```

2nd

```
constructor(private firestore: Firestore) { }
```

3rd

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
...
constructor(@Inject(Firestore) private firestore: Firestore)
```

Comment: 1. is now recommended by the angular core team and you may encounter issues with es2022 for the others.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, the dependency injection system can find a registered provider and inject the corresponding instance into a component or service in multiple ways. The key aspect that allows this matching to happen is the use of a token.

In the examples you provided, the token used to identify the dependency is the type of the class itself (`Firestore`). The Angular dependency injection system maintains an internal collection of registered providers and their associated tokens. When a component or service requests a dependency, Angular looks for a provider that matches the token.

Now let's break down the three different ways the dependency can be injected:

> 1. Using `inject` function:

```js
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
...
private firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);
```

Here, the `inject` function is imported from `@angular/core`, and it allows you to explicitly request a dependency by passing the token (in this case, the `Firestore` class). The function internally uses the Angular dependency injection system to find and return the appropriate instance.

> 2. Using constructor parameter:

```js
constructor(private firestore: Firestore) { }
```

In this case, the dependency is requested as a parameter in the constructor of the class. The `private` keyword is a shorthand notation provided by Angular that combines declaring the parameter and assigning it to a class property. When the component is created, the Angular dependency injection system automatically resolves the dependency based on the token (`Firestore` class) and injects the instance.

> 3. Using `@Inject` decorator:

```js
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
...
constructor(@Inject(Firestore) private firestore: Firestore) { }
```

Here, the `@Inject` decorator from `@angular/core` is used to explicitly specify the token for the dependency. By applying the decorator to the constructor parameter, you indicate that the dependency should be resolved using the token (`Firestore` class).

In summary, the Angular dependency injection system uses tokens to match requested dependencies with registered providers. The token can be the type of the class itself or a custom token specified using `@Inject`. This allows Angular to find and inject the appropriate instance into components and services, regardless of the specific way the dependency is requested.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow,  Akash Lukhi!

Your three answers here so far all appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.